# Java: Sqlexception : Non supported SQL92 token at position: 178

Tags: java, sql, oracle, apache-camel

Getting following error while hitting sql query against Oracle:

```
CaughtExceptionType: java.sql.SQLException, CaughtExceptionMessage: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 178, StackTrace: java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 178
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.handleODBC(OracleSql.java:1306)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.parse(OracleSql.java:1192)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.getSql(OracleSql.java:326)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.getSqlBytes(OracleSql.java:661)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:202)
```

Trying to hit following query:

```
SELECT PERSONID as employeeid, employeeid as employeenumber, employeetype FROM MASTERDATA.EMPLOYEE_DATA WHERE   (domainprefix='TCORP' or  domainprefix='CORP') 
 and PERSONID IN(30654,825,28538,33620,870,12938,33317,3487,32846,696,61641,27281,34926,53427,29694,59265,59698,42931,53623,37170,48909,61174,14202,27225,50375,38585,56251,30604,56292,17236,48999,59910,50173,21696,18027,55743,5363,37579,1838,61398,41250,42846,1845,56608,49717,33625,8465,54709,61564,60317,10235,35501,5059,60654,52373,38523,58838,5361,55502,10330,24606,37422,56198,41283,33794,19254,59017,50801,59545,45678,56049,25126,35400,54479,7308,6429,23022,62358,55952,28449,48274,54156,53473,53708,34612,37418,59084,55640,35407,54487,4720,4621,4631,4614,4727,24890,61465,4728,60489,40356,58959,54897,17497,38449,58056,58074,2649,36423,4843,4854,14470,4677,57956,57981,49218,24715,15620,5707,5709,51319,15256,62559,61987,27593,57661,47874,15297,5372,12885,16119,21831,46329,6902,24176,12956,31591,40545,9964,12805,57569,56107,62004,60267,39234,34769,60265,23029,48472,38061,54242,26657,34887,33762,61126,15812,7701,1938,7860,38522,22457,6304,2567,3268,53135,57359,55500,44961,56158,59224,18733,5409,12277,24935,31471,16623,49804,29478,8538,40766,58584,15404,3343,57360,41604,25946,25521,58251,53952,55851,56282,24758,60623,48798,25552,28610,53794,51585,59753,59042,59790,28233,28589,16055,15995,50502,28600,16786,25054,51962,21372,61487,25568,30872,60156,55275,16795,21900,18751,63048,15409,32526,25081,61430,58445,61799,30067,45811,61292,59036,52398,53249,21678,51329,59394,19708,47035,60748,61977,36735,50708,59255,59917,53950,15196,41728,58310,60427,61806,52192,61758,24314,15550,26803,28257,58979,47640,19722,62228,16796,63046,57263,61283,53797,15431,52974,59037,51330,51580,60424,51060,15473,60982,51746,61289,15427,58981,43327,28264,61427,15187,47851,50707,25058,61432,25986,31554,36335,55005,50754,55339,54634,28912,49382,55307,28911,15212,45470,29402,15204,61768,63042,55274,49102,15526,67322,45471,35490,55181,32859,32524,48320,23803,21367,28241,60999,15223,40872,23378,58575,24325,23425,16003,15619,55855,56931,59410,29756,48300,45806,32508,31566,51983,26812,30487,44759,56182,52204,21899,22840,10591,10582,11953,12114,60316,10548,10866,61127,12160,29267,50185,33679,35533,5452,10913,10771,55377,56798,56300,62194,38840,61604,55915,36837,55630,8295,59021,8507,49026,8746,8677,36544,62804,8397,55976,27175,49755,61815,45342,8196,42864,15569,10828,48012,53323,8443,51434,59405,25562,21011,31971,51985,31273,53796,56860,1965,56449,45650,7289,46014,63504,63471,63522,63503,63682,63703,63679,62499,64562,64169,64177,15240,64545,62529,62482,62616,64619,64852,65016,65058,65188,65191,65278,65327,65525,65613,65907,65970,65976,65978,66265,66309,66310,66347,66414,66468,66729,66750,66755,66889,66966,67215,67254,67282,67394,67395,67782,67623,67644,67749,67780,67823,67908,67933,68056,68095,68150,68229,68308,68458,68470,68481,68549,68551,68553,68606,68626,68627,68700,68711,68743,68922,68960,69058,69059,69153,69408,69431,69429,69454,69580,69650,69844,69907,69928,69987,70060,70095,70097,70099,70456,70683,70815,70821,70910,71016,71022,71066,71085,71109,71158,71201,71256,71282,71324,71352,71606,43320,71672,71678,71679,71736,71791,62489,62637,71918,71923,72031,70407,70408,70574,72203,72202,72224,72265,72329,72627,72703,72706,72708,72710,72711,72804,72758,7295,72872,72877,16011,72943,73067,73210,73358,73572,73627,73639,73720,73722,54972,73768,73938,74035,72762,74064,74176,74378,74389,74454,74530,74539,74545,74689,74879,74913,75058,75142,75236,75319,75380,75392,75423,75499,75510,75530,75533,75534,75854,75973,76049,76075,76086,76089,76164,76333,76404,76616,76624,76628,76686,76705,76890,76899,76935,76939,77099,77108,77110,77155,77185,77270,77308,77316,77344,77355,77357,77501,77512,77515,77538,77606,77623,77670,77684,77765,77771,77818,77828,77883,77904,77930,77932,77963,78009,78049,78092,78137,78139,78195,78318,78333,78334,78412,78410,78488,78523,78526,766003,766248,766252,766283,766299,766355,766360,766372,766383,766394,766406,766409,766416,766425,766429,766430,766433,766436,766455,766467,766469,766470,766471,766491,766492,766496,766499,766509,766512,766522,766523,766525,766534,766555,766565,766566,766574,766577,766583,766595,766732,766745,766754,766755,766756,766759,766761,766770,766771,766772,766779,766802,766822,766836,766853,766860,766865,766866,766868,766897,766905,766914,766917,766930,766932,766958,766959,766980,766983,766989,766998,767179,767180,767194,767197,767200,767201,767206,767207,767216,767223,767226,767227,767228,767245,767263,767269,27591,767276,767277,767282,767290,767294,767295,767309,767314,767326,767334,767360,767374,767380,767382,767388,767389,767401,767418,767419,767429,767434,767439,767440,767441,767443,767444,767445,767448,767458,767459,767460,767461,767462,767463,767464,767466,767474,767486,41301,767500,767507,767512,767521,767522,767523,767527,767528,767529,767530,767532,767558,767561,767583,767586,767588,767597,767600,767601,767602,767608,767617,767634,767659,767660,767669,767672,767683,767684,767685,767686,767687,767689,767699,767709,767724,767726,767727,767759,767767,767769,767770,767779,767783,767816,767819,767826,767832,767845,767854,767855,767856,767900,767908,767912,767919,767923,767933,767969,767970,768004,768030,768031,768032,768033,768050,768053,768054,768055,768056,768057,768058,768069,768108,768122,768134,768141,768176,768178,768196,768203,768217,768229,768276,768278,768317,768332,768375,768384,768389,768392,768393,768398,768460,768478,768482,768505,768507,768517,768533,768534,768536,768544,768546,768547,768549,768550,768551,768566,768573,768588,768589,768590,768599,768626,768628,768639,768723,768754,768756,61033,68112,68141,68966,74695,76429,76809,77978,761947,766300,766341,766342,766345,766346,766347,766359,766361,766362,766363,766364,766365,766366,766368,766369,766373,766374,766375,766379,766380,766381,766382,766384,766385,766399,766401,766407,766410,766423,766424,766426,766427,766428,766435,766438,766444,766454,766473,766480,766483,766484,766495,766497,766500,766517,766540,766543,766548,766549,766550,766551,766552,766560,766573,766584,766736,766739,766740,766750,766763,766798,766804,766806,766807,766815,766818,766823,766827,766839,766840,766842,766845,766861,766862,766863,766864,766870,766880,766881,766882,766884,766887,766888,766890,766891,766944,766948,766949,766979,766986,766987,766993,766995,767184,767186,767196,767204,767205,767208,767225,767236,767237,767238,767246,767251,767261,767264,767265,767275,767296,767310,767319,767320,767331,767345,767348,767353,767355,767369,767370,767371,767375,767390,767392,767400,767404,767411,767412,767446,767447,767454,767457,767465,767479,767484,767488,767489,767491,767492,767494,767508,767517,767536,767537,767538,767539,767540,767541,767542,767543,767544,767545,767547,767548,767551,767554,767556,767557,767559,767579,767580,767582,767587,767603,767633,767641,767648,767657,767662,767677,767678,767679,767681,767682,767693,767705,767706,767713,767717,767718,767719,767722,767750,767754,767773,767774,767776,767792,767793,767805,767806,767807,767809,767824,767825,767827,767861,767865,767885,767893,767894,767895,767902,767905,767910,767913,767915,767930,767931,767936,767940,767960,767961,767985,767986,768000,768008,768013,768026,768034,768041,768064,768065,22500,768073,768074,768077,768079,768101,768102,768103,768110,768128,768138,768139,768154,768155,768156,768159,768161,768185,768207,768208,768212,768216,768226,768239,768240,768241,768251,768252,768253,768254,768255,768256,768258,768269,768292,768293,768294,768295,768299,768301,768312,768316,768318,768320,768329,768330,768333,768352,768353,768354,768355,768358,768362,768364,768377,768378,768379,768390,768391,768402,768405,768452,768455,768456,768457,768458,768469,768470,768471,768472,768473,768474,768475,768476,768477,768481,768483,768484,768486,768493,768495,768504,768514,768515,768516,768521,768530,768531,768532,768542,768560,768565,768571,768579,768581,768582,768584,768592,768593,768595,768597,768598,768600,768601,768607,768615,768621,768632,768637,768638,768640,768641,768646,768655,768664,768665,768680,768683,768692,768697,768715,768716,768721,768725,768726,768727,768731,768732,768733,768734,768735,768739,768740,768741,768742,768751,768753,768760,768762)
```

When I try to hit from oracle then I get following:

```
ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000
```

When i shorten the size then it says following:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

When i put quotes around each number then it runs fine.

**Question**: What is actual reason I am getting "Non supported SQL92 token at position: 178"? Is it size or invalid number or anything else?

Code Snippet:

```
.setBody(constant(getEmployee() + " and PERSONID IN(${exchangeProperty.commaseperatedids})" ))
.to("jdbc:masterdata?outputClass=com.fudiel.integrator.model.Employee")
```

Comment: Is `personid` a `number`?  Or a `varchar2`?  There is a 1000 item limit for literals in the `IN` list-- I'm not sure why that would cause an the non-supported token error you're getting but I'm not sure it would make sense to spend a lot of time debugging that since you'd just be trying to figure out why you're not getting the correct error.  Where are these IDs coming from?  Assuming the source is the database, you can have a subquery in the IN list that returns as many values as you'd like.

Comment: Put those 1000+ values in a (temporary?) table, and JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to wrap numbers in quotes which is not valid, your first try to use more than 1000 entries in Oracle “IN” clause is not supported by default, so you might change your application to split the query in to several queries that each of them selects maximum 1000 elements.